# Custom Display Output for List of ObjA

Tags: python, ipython

We can register a custom type for say numpy.polynomial.polynomial with ipython display engine as follow

```
ip = get_ipython()

foramtter = ip.display_formatter.formatters['text/latex']

foramtter.for_type_by_name('numpy.polynomial.polynomial',
                             'Polynomial', display_func)
```

I would like to use the .for_type_by_name(...) method to register a custom display for a list of an specific type, say ObjA not just the type ObjA itself.

How can I do that?

Btw, I don't have access to the class that returns the list of ObjA.

Comment: You may want to add a python tag and provide a little more details.

Comment: Hmm... Thinking about this question again, I believe there must be a cleaner way by creating a custom Formatter like [Sage does this](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/master/src/sage/repl/display/formatter.py) and replacing `text/plain` one. Don't have time to try and come with working snippet at the moment, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a formatter for `list` objects that'd only act when it sees a list of ObjA's?

```
from decimal import Decimal   # Decimal is my ObjA here

ip = get_ipython()
formatter = ip.display_formatter.formatters['text/latex']

def format_list(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, list):
        return None
    if not all(isinstance(item, Decimal) for item in obj):
        return None
    return "$$[%s]$$" % ";".join(map(str, obj))

formatter.for_type_by_name('builtins', 'list', format_list)
```

It seems that if formatting function returns `None`, the formatter is ignored. At least it works for me:

```
In[2]: [Decimal("1"), Decimal("2"), "not a decimal"]
Out[2]: [Decimal("1"), Decimal("2"), "not a decimal"]

In[3]: [Decimal("1"), Decimal("2")]
Out[3] 1, 2  # LaTeX-formatted, yeah
```

This is a quite dirty hack, but unfortunately I don't see any other way (besides monkey patching `DisplayFormatter`, which is even dirtier, although it should be more powerful). If there is, hope someone would enlighten us.

Comment: In more recent versions of IPython, this does not work anymore, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53031043/5962321)