# How to override ipython displayhook?

Tags: python, ipython

I have defined my own displayhook that inherits from IPython.core.displayhook.DisplayHook.

I was unable to find any resources online as for the proper way of overriding the displayhook for an IPython shell. Currently, I am doing the following in ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/imports.py:

```
ipyShell = IPython.get_ipython()
ipyShell.displayhook = MyDisplayHook(shell=ipyShell)
ipyShell.displayhook_class = MyDisplayHook
sys.displayhook = ipyShell.displayhook
```

Which does not work, as after the ipython shell starts up, sys.displayhook is somehow switched back to the regular ipython display hook:

```
In [5]: print sys.displayhook
<IPython.core.displayhook.DisplayHook object at 0x7f1491853610>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone stumbles on this (like I did), the way to format IPython can actually be misleading at first glance when compared to the standard python displayhook.

In this answer, I try to detail first the different parts of IPython to clarify, then tackle the specific question of the OP (and mine) at the end.

In IPython, you can customize almost everything, only using methods that are quite far from the standard python `displayhook`.

What is called "hooks" in IPython (see the [doc](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.hooks.html?highlight=hooks) and [this example](https://github.com/securesystemslab/zippy/blob/master/zippy/benchmarks/src/benchmarks/sympy/sympy/interactive/printing.py#L163)) is actually something aimed at altering the behavior of the shell.

Alternatively can change how the **editor** looks like, i.e. the

```
In [5]: def foo():
   ...:     return 'foo'
   ...:
```

interface, and specifically the `In [5]:` and `...:` parts.
For that, you can have a look at the [IPython doc](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html#custom-prompts) to see how to do that with `Prompts`.

Eventually, to alter how the output of a python object is formatted, I had to use the IPython **formatters** (cf. [source code](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/formatters.py)) and the **pretty printing** functions defined [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/0de2f49cceca3d670e67a923a96b45fc2dc43294/IPython/lib/pretty.py#L740).

For instance, if you want to change the default `dict` formatting from

```
{'axon_angle': 305.010625458 degree,
 'observables': ['length',
   'num_growth_cones'],
 'random_rotation_angles': True}
```

to

```
{
  'axon_angle'            : 305.010625458 degree,
  'observables'           : [
    'length',
    'num_growth_cones',
  ],
  'random_rotation_angles': True
}
```

You can use something like

```
def dict_formatter(obj, p, cycle):
    if cycle:
        return p.text('{...}')
    start = '{'
    end   = '}'
    step = 2
    p.begin_group(step, start)
    keys = obj.keys()
    max_len = 0
    for k, v in obj.items():
        max_len = max(max_len, len(str(k)))

    if obj:
        p.breakable()
    for idx, key in p._enumerate(keys):
        if idx:
            p.text(',')
            p.breakable()
        p.pretty(key)
        wlen = max_len-len(str(key))
        p.text(' '*wlen + ': ')
        p.pretty(obj[key])
    if obj:
        p.end_group(step, '')
        p.breakable()
        p.text(end)
    else:
        p.end_group(step, end)

import IPython
ip = IPython.get_ipython()
formatter = ip.display_formatter.formatters['text/plain']
formatter.for_type(dict, dict_formatter)
```