# Tweaking the representation of `bytes` objects

Tags: python, ipython

Representing a `bytes`-object, in Python, characters that decode to ASCII as non-whitespace printables are shown as ASCII, whereas all others are shown according to their hexadecimal value:

```
In [61]: print(bytes(range(256)))
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
```

Is there any way to tweak this behaviour in the interactive console?  When I'm inspecting binary data, the fact that some bytes happen to be decodable to a non-whitespace printable ASCII is completely uninteresting for me.  Of course, I can get the effect I see by

```
print(r"\x" + r"\x".join("{:02x}".format(x) for x in bytes(range(256))))
```

or write a similar function.  Can I apply this function to be used for any representation of `bytes`?  I don't want to change the interactive representation for any other type.  I'm using IPython 4.0.0.

Comment: If you're happy to just alter the appearance of `bytes(...)` rather than `print(bytes(...))` then you could just override `sys.displayhook` for your purposes.

Comment: @donkopotamus Possibly.  But [with IPython](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35913346/974555)?

Comment: Should work fine ... you can store existing `sys.displayhook` and redirect things you don't care about to it

Comment: @donkopotamus I remember trying it with IPython many years ago and not figuring out how.  I might try again but the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35913346/974555) suggests the situation persists.